# Is there a way to store Arabic dates with Postgres?

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql

I am a PHP developer and I am working on a project in which I need to store Arabic dates in my database.

However, I have created the application and embedded a JavaScript Arabic calender in it.

Now when I select a date, e.g `12/02/1442`, and press the save button, it gives me the following error:

```
Year Out Of Range
```

Comment: Please provide more info - code, DB schema, SQL statements etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These dates (Arabic, Jalali, ...) usually have problems with SQL servers. In my experience, there are 3 ways to handle it:

1. Using *character* types for storing dates into the fields with any custom format. (The problem are: Manipulating, arithmetic, sorting,... which they are hard to implement)
2. Using *integer* or *fixed character* type for storing dates, like `14420101` for `1/1/1442`. (Same as first one, but sorting is solved)
3. Using *date* or *timestamp* type for storing, you should convert dates to standard date format before storing it into the database, and when you're reading them convert them back. This method needs a external programming language to handle *(Usually there is an external language)*. Or you can write a internal functions in your database.

Just storing dates then methods 1 and 2 are enough.

Otherwise, I suggest third approach, because you can use `date` and `time` pre-defined functions which exists in database servers or programming languages.

*For example you can use `date_diff()` easily in PHP, or use postgres internal functions for dates.*

Comment: Regarding 2): Sorting would be much easier, if the integer is encoded as 14420212.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a perfect application to write a custom data type.  Maybe someone has already done it, or you could start.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports input and output of dates and timestamps as Julian Day. The two appropriate sections in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-formatting.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-datetime.html

That might help if you want to do calculations in the database. If that's not an issue, just store the dates as *Masoud M.* has suggested.